# When I compile this with Ant the exclude tag does not work

Tags: eclipse, ant

This is Ant build.xml:

```
    <target name = "build" depends="clean" description = "Compile main source tree java files">
      <mkdir dir = "${build.dir}"/>

      <javac destdir = "${build.dir}" source = "1.6" target = "1.6" debug = "true"
         deprecation = "false" optimize = "false" failonerror = "false" 
        includeantruntime="true" >

        <src path = "${src.dir}"/>
        <include name="com/**/*" />

        <exclude name="${src.dir}/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java"/>
         <classpath refid = "master-classpath"/>

      </javac>
   </target>
```

and this is the console output:

```
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/classes
[javac] /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/src/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java:3: package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import static org.junit.Assert.*;
[javac]                        ^
[javac] /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/src/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java:7: package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import org.junit.Test;
[javac]                 ^
[javac] /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/src/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java:13: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class Test
[javac] location: class com.cheom.db.DBMethodTest
[javac]     @Test
[javac]      ^
[javac] /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/src/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java:3: package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import static org.junit.Assert.*;
[javac]                        ^
[javac] /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/src/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java:7: package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import org.junit.Test;
[javac]                 ^
[javac] /Users/josh/Google Drive/workDocs/JEE/MonitorDBFlow/src/com/cheom/db/DBMethodTest.java:13: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class Test
[javac] location: class com.cheom.db.DBMethodTest
[javac]     @Test
[javac]      ^
[javac] 3 errors
[javac] Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I want exclude DBMethodTest.java filem but exclude tag does not work. I tried it in Eclipse IDE and terminal with Ant version is 1.9.4.  Is  there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

There are no JUnit jars in your classpath.

> -cp path or -classpath path
>   Specify where to find user class files, and (optionally) annotation processors and source files. This class path overrides the user class path in the CLASSPATH environment variable. If neither CLASSPATH, -cp nor -classpath is specified, the user class path consists of the current directory. See Setting the Class Path for more details.
>   [javac doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I don't know how to do in my case, because I exclude all classes using JUnit jar. So when the classes using 'JUnit jar' are excluded, do I still need JUnit jar